# java merge two flux without duplicates

Tags: java, flux, spring-webflux, reactor

I have two fluxes and I want to merge them avoiding duplicates. How can I do this?

Here are my fluxes:

```java
Flux<Tweet> remoteTweets = Flux.just(
        new Tweet("tag1",new TweetID("text","name"),"userimage","country","place"),
        new Tweet("tag2",new TweetID("text","name"),"userimage","country","place")
);

Flux<Tweet> localTweets = Flux.just(
        new Tweet("tag1",new TweetID("text","name"),"userimage","country","place")
);
```

Merging these two is giving me `tag 1, tag1, tag2`, but I want `tag1, tag2`.

The order is not important.

Comment: Call [`.distinct()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#distinct--) on your merged Flux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
     SpringApplication.run(BackendApplication.class, args);
  String[] strings = {"a","b","c"};
    Flux.merge(Flux.fromArray(strings),Flux.fromArray(strings))
            .distinct()
            .map(s -> {
                System.out.println(s);
                return s;
            }).subscribe();
```

but in your case in Tweet object you need to override equals and hashcode 
be aware distinct firstly see if hashcode is equal then .equal function

if you are using intellij try alt+ insert and click equal and hashCode